# Please help with infinite sum with more than one variable

Tags: summation

I built this sum for an algorithm, but am having trouble figuring out where to start solving it. If I could get it down to a partial sum, I could use limits to solve it, but its been so long since I've done anything other than the most basic summations, I could really use a finger in the right direction on where to start.

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  k  (1 - (1 - p^k)^n)
$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. I've edited your post to make the math look nicer. You may check some tips on [ask], on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already.

Comment: The exact expression may be obtained using the binomial expansion: $$(1-x)^n = 1 - n x + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} x^2 - \ldots +{^n}C_j (-1)^j x^j + \ldots + (-1)^n x^n$$

Comment: What is  the value of $p$?

Comment: Hint: 1) expand $1- (1-p^k)^n$ by binomial theorem (assuming $n$ is a positive integer) 2) apply the identity
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty kz^k = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ for $|z| < 1$.